# Why does a pivot of a parameter have the same distribution for all values of the parameter?

Tags: statistics

If the random variable $Q(X_1,..X_n,\theta)$ is a pivot for $\theta$, why does $Q(X_1,..X_n,\theta)$ have the same distibution for all values of $\theta$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the definition of a pivot. From Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity):

"More formally, let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be a random sample from a distribution that depends on a parameter (or vector of parameters) $\theta$. Let $g(X,\theta)$ be a random variable whose distribution is the same for all $\theta$. Then $g$ is called a pivotal quantity (or simply a pivot)".

So, asking why pivots have this property is a little bit like asking why square numbers can be written as the product of some number with itself: That's what it means.

A more interesting question might be what good pivots are. The Wikipedia article also states some indications of this. One main example is for the construction of confidence intervals. Consider e.g. a model where $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent and normally distributed with some mean $\mu$ and unit variance, where we imagine that we do not know the true value of $\mu$. If the true mean is $\mu$, then
$$
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-\mu)
$$
follows a standard normal distribution, so this is a pivot. This in particular means that no matter the true $\mu$, it holds that
$$
  P\left(-1.96 \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-\mu)\le 1.96\right) = 0.95,
$$
since 1.96 is the 97.5% quantile of the standard normal distribution. This, by rearrangement, implies that
$$
  P\left(\mu -1.96 / \sqrt{n} \le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\le \mu+1.96 / \sqrt{n}\right) = 0.95.
$$
Thus, with 95 percent probability, the empiricial mean $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ is within $1.96/\sqrt{n}$ of the true mean, no matter what the true mean is. This lends credence to our using the empirical mean as an estimator of the true mean: Our analysis, using the pivotal quantity above, yields results on how well the empirical mean is capable of estimating the true mean.

Comment: Say though that if we let $T=\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{S/ \sqrt{n}}$~$t_{n-1}$ with $S$ the sample standard deviation, $\mu$ the population mean, $\bar{X}$ the sample mean, n the number of samples and $t_{n-1}$ the student$_{(n-1)}$ distribution. Then T is a function of $\mu$ but not a function of any unknown parameter and its distribution does not depend on any unknown parameter, so it is a pivot for $\mu$. However why does T have the same distribution for all values of $\mu$? Surely if I change $\mu$ I get a different distribution of $T$.

Comment: * $\mu$ unknown

Comment: In a word, no. If you change $\mu$, you don't get a different distribution of $T$: When $\mu$ changes the change in the $\mu$ in $\bar{X}-\mu$ is compensated precisely by the change in the distribution of $\bar{X}$ by the change of $\mu$.